# examples of web services

Tags: java, web-services

I had made numerous web applications in java..

I read a lot about web services

But don't know how to make working example in web services?

Also, don't have any idea about ejb,jmx,etc.

Is it necessary to put web application on some server in order to implement web services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you define a "web service", it can be as simple or as complex as you like. Many REST-based web services are just normal web applications that return JSON as their response instead of HTML. At the other end of the spectrum, there are SOAP (and others) that are much more involved, but can basically be called just like any other method by the consuming application.

Comment: I find that REST is easier to learn & implement than SOAP based Web services. But for beginner use, it is recommended to start with REST?

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal - REST is very simple, which is good for both performance and implementation. In general, stick with the simplest solution you can and only get more complicated if you need to. Most applications don't have any need for web services at all.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal - If you find answers to be helpful, please remember to up-vote them to show your support.

Comment: It does not necessarily have to be returned in JSON - it can be XML or text. Just making sure the OP is aware of it and does not confuse rest with only JSON as the valid media.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Apache Axis2[1] to create and consume web services. This article[2] shows the steps to how to write a simple web service.

[1] http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/

[2] http://wso2.org/library/95